# How to use last to see how many times users logged in?

Tags: login, logging, sort, uniq, last-command

I need to see how many times users logged in.

I used `last | sort | uniq -c` but it gave me bad data

I need to sort them by number of times they logged in and only show username and number of time.

for example:

```
username       number of logins
userb          36
usera          12
userd          12
userc          8
```

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: `last | cut -c 1-8 | sort | uniq -c` does the job but does not the format it the way you want. it also reports blank lines, reboots etc. `awk` will do the job better.

Comment: Note that last only gives logins since the last time wtmp was rotated.

Comment: I have bash shell. as for what distro its a custom one that my work uses. though it is up to date. anything that worked on my ubuntu has worked there too.

Comment: ```last | cut -c 1-8 | sort | uniq -c | sort -r``` worked great. thanks.

Comment: Questions about custom distros that are not official Ubuntu (or it's flavors) are off topic here. Please frame your question for your Ubuntu computer.

Comment: it worked on my official ubuntu 22.04. and I tested it on my work server and it worked there too. I looked at it and it seems to be ubuntu 18 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @user68186

the answer is `last | cut -c 1-8 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r`